# Grabbing nested parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

**Context**
For a bike order system, users can first fill in the bike_type (e.g. 'mountainbike') and consequently pick a bike (e.g. 'yellow mountainbike').

When a user enters a bike_type, but forgets the bike, the form needs to render again so a user can fill in the missing bike.

**Problem**
The bike order schema has

- a join table between order and bike ('order_bike')
- and a bike belongs to a bike_type.

*--> Therefore, when users first fill in a bike_type, this bike_type needs a bike to connect to an order.*

**How can I grab the bike_type in my create controller, so it automatically renders the last filled in bike_type in case the form needs to re-render when it's not filled in correctly?**

Parameters sent

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"NqEb3EhNDOYFI12tYLCp9akDtVnEbiA4skR5qmVygwnRv+GkELvDTEJhU8/o5Orvmsiaxk7PIPbawD9CZvWLYw==",
 "order"=>
  {"order_bikes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"bikes"=>{"bike_type"=>"166"}, "bike_id"=>"Select bike"}},
   "arrival"=>"",
   "departure"=>"",
   "order_contact_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "street"=>"", "street_number"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "city"=>"", "country"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Save & proceed to additional options",
 "bike_store_id"=>"21"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the bike_type from the params like this:

`params[:order][:order_bikes_attributes]['0'][:bikes][:bike_type]`

Comment: Thank you the proposed solution. When I try to grab the parameter in my controller via this solution (```Order.find(params[:order][:order_bikes_attributes]['0'][:bikes][:bike_type]) ```), I get an ```NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass```.

Comment: So somewhere in that line it returns nil, to figure out where it returns nil you could do some debugging. For example in the controller add: `puts params[:order]` check in the console what it returns, is it nil or is it the correct param? If it's the correct param, go a step further by adding `[:order_bikes_attributes]` to it. This way you will find where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you. It was a really stupid mistake, I entered Order.find instead of BikeType.find..

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to you use [dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method to avoid `nil` errors.

```
params.dig('order', 'order_bikes_attributes', '0', 'bikes', 'bike_type')
```

Comment: If I understand the dig method correctly, when the bike_type would be nil it would return nil without giving an error?